# How can I convert serializer data into dict type in Django

Tags: python, django, generics, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> from generic.models import banner
>>> query = banner.objects.all()
>>> querydata = serializers.serialize("json",query)
>>> querydata
'[{"model": "generic.banner", "pk": 1, "fields": {"banner": "banner1", "link": null, "category": "bus", "status": "active"}}, {"model": "generic.banner", "pk": 3, "fields": {"banner": "banner2", "link": null, "category": "Mobile", "status": "active"}}]'
>>> type(querydata)
<class 'str'>
```

In Querydata i am getting a string but i want to convert the querydata in dict in below format:

```
{'bus':{'model': 'generic.banner', 'pk': 1, 'fields': {'banner': 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Paymentapi\\cbanner\\cban_7500.png', 'link': null, 'category': 'bus', 'status': 'active'}}, 'Mobile':{'model': 'generic.banner', 'pk': 3, 'fields': {'banner': 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Paymentapi\\cbanner\\cban_7318.png', 'link': null, 'category': 'Mobile', 'status': 'active'}}}
```

Comment: Your output does not match the input, e.g. there is no base-level key `bus` in your `querydata`. I would look into `json.loads` for the transformation from string=>dict though.

Comment: I know my output didn't match.

Comment: I want to manipulate the input and convert the input in the output format

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert string to dict, simply do

```
import json
qs = json.loads(<your string>)
query_data = qs[0]
```

Now, `query_data` will be of type `dict`.

Comment: i already use josn.loads but it provide in list type not in dict type

Comment: That is because your query data is a list of dict. See it again. I am updating my answer to extract the dict out of it.

Comment: Actually, Querydata format is [{},{}], there are dict in a list, If i do query_data = qs[0], i give only first set of dict  but i want both dict in a dict .

Comment: then you convert it to dict. Do, `dict(qs)`, you get a {{}, {}, ...}. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Guys for helping me What output I want I am  able to manipulate it, But i have one question, can you tell it is right way , i shared the code below:                                                                                         
    query_json = json.loads(querydata)
    dic_data = {}
    querylen = len(query_json)

     for i in range(querylen):
  for k,v in query_json[i].items():
   if k == 'fields':
    for m,n in v.items():
     if m=='category':
      dic_data[n] =v